# Tensorflow: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order only when running in terminal

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I encounter some problem while running the python script on Google cloud computing instance, with python 3.6, tensorflow 1.13.1. I see several people encounter similar problems of loops in computational graph on stackoverflow. But none of it really find the culprit for it. And I observe something interesting so maybe someone experienced can figure it out.

The error message is like this:

```
2019-05-28 22:28:57.747339: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:704] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2019-05-28 22:28:57.754195: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:704] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

My script for train.py will look like this:

```
import A,B,C

...


def main():
    ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So I will show my two ways to run this script:

VERSION1:

In terminal,

```
python3 train.py
```

This gives me the error like I state above. When I only use CPU, i notice it throws me something like `failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected`. So I add GPU to my instance but the loop in computational graph is still there.

VERSION 2(This is where weird thing happens):

I just simply copy, with nothing changed, the code in `main` to the jupyter notebook and run there. Then suddenly, no error occurs anymore.

I don't really know what's going on under the hood. I just notice the message at the beginning of the running is not the same between two different ways of running the code.

If you encounter the same problem, copy to jupyter notebook might help directly. I would really like share more info if someone has any ideas what might possible cause this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out, no matter what, I choose a wrong way to build the graph at the beginning, which will not give the `loop` in my perspective. The `loop error` give me an idea I'm doing something wrong. But the interesting question I mentioned above is still not answered! However, I'd like to share my error so anyone see the `loop error` should think whether you're doing the same thing as me.

In the `input_fn`, I use `tensor.eval()` to get corresponding `numpy.array` in the middle to interact with data outside of that function. I choose not to use `tf.data.Dataset` because the whole process is complicated and I can't compress the whole thing into `Dataset` directly. But it turns out this approach sabotage the static computational graph design of Tensorflow. So during training, it trains on the same batch again and again. So my two cents advice is that if you want to achieve something super complex in your `input_fn`. It's likely you will be better off or even only doing the right thing by using the old fashioned modelling way- `tf.placeholder`.